# Python Merge Join with multiple join columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two tables with following structure:

```
    Table 1 
ID  City Country    
1   India   
2   Delhi   
3   America 
4   New York    
5   Germany 

Table 2     
ID  Country City
1   India   
2   India   Delhi
3   America 
4   America New York
5   Germany 


Select  * from table1           
Left outer join table2          
on citycountry  = city or citycountry = country
```

My task is to implement the same in pandas for multiple join conditions `"citycountry  = city or citycountry = country"`. How should I do it in pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've stored your data as [DataFrames](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), you can use pandas' [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.merge(table1, table2, 
     left_on=  ['citycountry', 'citycountry'],
     right_on= ['country', 'city'], 
     how = 'left')
```